# Uart higher BaudRate problems in Raspberry Pi

Tags: c, linux, raspberry-pi, uart, raspbian

Any idea why my native C application can't reach higher baudrates than 38400?
I have exactly the same application which i successfully initialize to listen and transmit on 9600, 19200, 38400 baudes. However as soon as i set up for 57600 i get garabage out of the transmitter(receiver i don't know). I'm listening to it with a terminal so i see the garbage directly from pin header.

I use Raspbian and uart on Pin 14 and 15 of the GPIO header.

Is there any adjustment of some precission fraction which causes the problem?

Right now i just do this (and it works):
    cfsetispeed(&options,B38400);
    cfsetospeed(&options,B38400);
    tcsetattr(uart0_filestream, TCSANOW, &options);
    fcntl(uart0_filestream, F_SETFL,O_NDELAY);

TX part:
    int a = write(uart0_filestream, StartOfTheMessage, Length);

Thank you.

Comment: Not a solution but debugging ideas.  1) What do you send and what is the garbage? 2) Try looping back your transmit data to itself and see if you can read what you transmit.  3) When you transmit at 57600 and listen with a terminal, you report garbage.  But if you listen at other rates such as 38400, 115200, 19200 with your terminal wile still sending at 57600, what do you see?

Answer (score 0):

Your UART wires do not support the higher baud rate.

Comment: I checked the issue with both Jumper and Oscilloscope and finally i noticed that the B38400 which is speed from the termios.h is the highest implemented baudrate. The cfsetispeed(&options,B38400); cfsetospeed(&options,B38400) above these baudrates don't change anyghing as the B57600 simply doesn't exist according to the termios.h documentation. Do you know any other ready library which i can easly use to get the speed? Thanks